Making simple objecs in real life using uv map
Good morning, I recently saw the video on YouTube which is below, and it inspired me to create a more complex object using Blender.
This video
And I want to get a uv map that has a consistent scale, and according to uv map create object out of flat sheet metal or paper.
And I have a question for you, is there any option to see the most optimal uv-map to create object in real life?
I tried to do something, but it didn't work out very well
Here I made a simple object and used smart uv project with an angle limit of 0°

and here I split the parts and created smart uv project with an angle limit of 0°

I mean- have parts in the UV map that can actually be bend together, and those that need to be coupled should be separate
Maybe you know programs that allow you to make such a UV map

To get the separations (UV islands) to better match the cuts in the video you need to add UV seams on the model where you want the separations to be.
This is done by selecting the relevant edge loops then with the edges selected open the UV drop-down menu and from there choose the Mark Seams option. The edges with UV seams will now appear red on the model.

Next with all of the model selected open the UV menu again and this time choose the Unwrap > Conformal method.
In the lower right hand corner of the 3D viewport you will find the Last Operator panel where you can modify the space between the UV islands.

Slightly different UV seams may give you an UV unwrap more like how the cuts are in the video.

Checking the UV proportions, circumference of cylinder to length, the result seems OK.
Note: Looking more closely I now think the Angle Based  method gives a better UV unwrap for this particular model than the Conformal method that I suggested earlier..

